# C# SQL Columns into ComboBox

Tags: c#

My SQL query isn't dropping anything into the combobox. The connection seems to be made but the while loop doesn't seem to work. Can anybody tell me what it wrong?

```
string sqltable = ("dbo.SLTDS_C"+id+"_table");  

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + server   + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Integrated Security=" + security);  
con.Open();
```

string sqldatapull = ("select name from syscolumns where id = object_id('" + sqltable + "') order by name asc");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqldatapull, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

```
while (dr.Read())  
{  
    sqldatapull = dr[0].ToString();  
    comboBox1.Items.Add(sqldatapull);  
}  

dr.Close();  
con.Close();
```

---

Correction code:
string sqldatapull = ("select name from syscolumns where id = object_id('" + sqltable + "') order by name asc");

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting results back with that query?

Comment: no i'm not   
 string sqldatapull = ("select name from syscolumns where id = object_id('" + sqltable + "') order by name asc");  

fixed it all.

Comment: is there any reason you aren't using parameters/markers instead of just string concat?  just trying to avoid sql injection down the line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're including `dbo.` as part of the table name.  If you run

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

You will see that the table names have no schema in the `TABLE_NAME` column.